# UpdateOnSubmit from dbml?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have some generated classes representing a table from a dbml file

inserting a record in the table works fine with Name as a primary key

```
  dbDataContext nc = new dbDataContext(connectionstring);

  Action action = new Action();
  action.Name = "1234"; // primary key

  nc.Actions.InsertOnSubmit(action);
  nc.SubmitChanges();
```

But how to update a record when Name already exists? There seems to be no UpdateOnSubmit or anything. There doesnt seem to be a clear answer on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get the record from database,and then do the update in that object and save the changes.

```
Action action = nc.Actions.FristOrDefault(e=>e.Name="1234");

if(action!=null)
{
  action.SomeOtherProperty="NewValue";
}

nc.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

Handle both the add and update cases

```
public void Persist(Company company)
{
  var companyInDb = _dbSet.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == company.Id);
  if (companyInDb != null)
  {
    _context.Entry(companyInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(company);
  }
   else
  {
    _dbSet.Add(company);
  }
    _context.SaveChanges();
 }
```